# Turning on Location Service via Code (no exploits)

Tags: android, gps

I know this has been asked a lot in the past and i can't find an example without using exploits or jailbreaking the phone. But can someone tell me how my Samsung Watch (S2 no GPS) is able to turn on my phones Location service when i activate the emergency feature?

I know that according to the Android API you need do call startResolutionForResult() to ask for the user's permission to change the location settings. I was just curious how my Samsung watch is able to do it without showing a dialog. If i deactivate WiFi and Location on my phone and then start the emergency mode (pushing the power button three times), a few seconds later WiFi and Location are both activated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is "Only a system app can do that."

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to on location services without users concern programmatically, but it is possible to open gps settings when the gps is off and ask the user to switch on it.